# Text on image while hovering with opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made opacity at image while I hover , everything is fine. But text which appears is too transparent, and almost not visible. How to fix it?

```
<div class="projects">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="img/task_proj.jpg">
        <span class="overlay">Task Manager</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfNSW/

Here it is with js

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Comment: yes, please.  I', not sure I understand what your asking

Comment: @FlakDiNenno I believe the OP is asking how to fix the translucent text (overlay class).

Comment: and which text are you talking about exactly?  text within your image? or the text in the span class, i.e. "**Task Manager**" in `<span class="overlay">Task Manager</span>`

Comment: Your fiddle has no HTML in it, it uses jQuery but it doesn't load it.

Comment: I want the text in span class to appear when I hover on image@FlakDiNenno

Comment: you left out your html... here's an updated one for everyone:  [http://jsfiddle.net/flak/nCEQy/](http://jsfiddle.net/flak/nCEQy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to make the image translucent

http://jsfiddle.net/bfNSW/2/

remove

```
.projects a:hover{
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}
```

add

```
.projects a:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}
```

If you put the opacity on the anchor then it will affect everything in the anchor. In your case, you only need the image to be translucent so just target the image instead of the entire anchor

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're changing the opacity of `<a>`. Since, the `<span>` is inside that `<a>`, its opacity is affected to. Try changing the opacity of just the `<img>`.

```
.projects a:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bfNSW/3/).

Answer (score 0):

When the text is present inside the element which is transparent,Then the text itself also becomes Transparent.
To Solve this problem,Put the text division outside the element to which you have applied transparency,Then use appropriate styles to place text on the division.

### Normally it is done using styles

`position:relative;
  bottom: 10px; //or an height to which you want to raise it relative to the parent element.`